Can a Magus expend a Studious Spell slot to Prepare a Staff?
When a Prepared Caster prepares a staff as part of their daily preparations, they may expend one spell slot to add an additional number of charges equal to that slots rank to the staff.
So, for example, a 7th level magus could expend a 4th rank spell slot, to take their staff from having 4 charges to having 8 charges.
At 7th level, the magus also gains the Studious Spells feature.

Your hybrid study grants you additional spells that can enhance your power in combat. You gain two special 2nd-level studious spell slots, which can be used to prepare spider climb, true strike, water breathing, and an additional spell depending on your hybrid study. You add any spells from this class feature to your spellbook.

This means that the 7th level Magus, in addition to their 3rd and 4th rank slots, has two 2nd rank slots, which can only be used to prepare a narrow selection of spells.
Can one of these slots be expended to add charges to a staff? For example, to take the aforementioned 7th level magi's stave from 4 charges to 6?

As for why this is even a question: from a balance perspective, this is functionally a 50% increase in the value of these slots - since they are locked to 2nd rank (at this point), but will nearly always be used for Sure Strike (a rank 1 spell with no upcast benefit), if you have a staff with Sure Strike on it (such as the Spellstriker Staff), you are functionally turning 2 studious slots into 3. (and/or turning one of them into an offensive slot that can be used for a 2nd rank attack spell like Acid Arrow).

This could have interesting implications for most spellcasting classes. There are a lot of special use Spell Slots, such as Clerics' Fonts.

A Spell Slot is a Spell Slot
It is hard to prove a negative, but I could not see any indication that Divine Font spell slots, Studious Spell slots, or slots you get from your Arcane School could not be used in anything that are powered by spells.
Channel Smite is usually powered by Divine Font, and I have never seen anyone question that.
Some (most?) Arcane School spells have horrible scaling, and it has been proposed in several forums that these you can use to add extra charges to staves.
About balance
Even on 13th level, Studious Spells give you only a 4th rank slot, so 4 extra Sure Strikes. In exchange, you cannot have property runes, which on 13th level could add 2d6 damage. I find this strong, but not broken.

The lack of property runes is generally solved with a feat or focus spell.

@LessPop_MoreFizz how?

Depending on the hybrid study in question, Fused Staff, Runic Impression, and Student of the Staff all provide solid options. (In the case of Fused Staff, you wouldn't be using the slots for True Strikes, but, as you've noted, that's a pretty fair trade).
